# "At your university" - does university take a capital letter?

Tags: capitalization, letter-writing

In the following sentence:

> I would be humbled to partake in the tradition of excellence in Wizardry at your university.

Does "university" (referring to an actual institution) take a capital letter "U"? Why or why not?

Comment: No it wouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not capitalized because it does not name an individual place or organization.

If "Excellence in Wizardry" is the university's slogan, then *excellence* should be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it would be lowercase. But the fact that Wizardry is capitalized suggests that perhaps this is in (a late version of) Early Modern English in which case all 'important' nouns, including both Wizardry and University, would be capitalized.